# JPA - Cannot refresh database immediately after merge() - getEntityManager().refresh() has no effect

Tags: hibernate, jpa, seam

Im editing a value of a list from a list view page and meeting an issue that I can not refresh database immediately after calling getEntityManager().merge().
So, I have to ***refresh one more time so that the system returns accurate data*** result that I've edited even called getEntityManager().refresh() but still no effect.

```
getEntityManager().merge(transactions);
getEntityManager().flush();
getEntityManager().refresh(transactions);
```

I've researched so many posts of this problem before posting this and it took me plenty of time.
Sorry for either my bad English or bad coding. I'm a newbie.
Thanks alot !

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/rponte/1690560) page.

Comment: thank you.. this's also so useful to me to understand more but still does not help my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution already..This's a little related to Jboss Seam framework i'm using 
To display list page view, i used ***getEntityManage()*** of ***EntityQuery*** of Seam.
 Meanwhile in Editing it, i was using getEntityManage() of ***EntityHome***.
This leads to refresh() or clear() in EntityHome have no effect anyway and still stored cache until i reloaded the page.
I should have cleared cache in getEntityManage of ***EntityQuery*** rather than clearing the one of ***EntityHome*** by recalling the list searching query or simply calling getEntityManage.clear() in ***EntityQuery***
Hope this 's useful ! thanks